# Aws StepFunctions & Lambdas, Return Payload Is Sometime NULL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Problem:
In the context of a StepFunction that loop on a single Lambda, sometimes the returned Payload from the Lambda is null. If I rerun the exact same loop iteration with the same input, the Payload is not necessary null.

Using:
NodeJS 20 Runtime
Async/Await Pattern
EsModules Style

Having this StepFunction definition:

```
{
  "Comment": "Ingest Large Dataset",
  "StartAt": "Ingest_Dataset",
  "States": {
    "Ingest_Dataset": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:AccountID:function:LambdaName:$LATEST",
        "Payload.$": "$.Payload"
      },
      "Next": "IsMoreToProcess"
    },
    "IsMoreToProcess": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.Payload.continueProcessing",
          "BooleanEquals": true,
          "Next": "Ingest_Dataset"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Done"
    },
    "Done": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```

Having this Lambda definition:

```
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { parse } from 'csv-parse';

import { safeHandler } from '/opt/nodejs/Wrapper.mjs'
import { logger } from '/opt/nodejs/Logger.mjs'

const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: "eu-west-3" });

const __PREFIX = 'TASK Lambda / Ingest Dataset'

export const handler = async (event) => {
  return await safeHandler(__PREFIX, async () => {
    const db = getDb()
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body || '{}')
    const key = body.key
    const offset = body.offset || 0;
    const limit = body.limit || 1000;
    const countTry = body.countTry || 0;
    const maxTry = 10
    let headers = body.headers || null;
    let currentRow = 0;
    let processedRows = 0;

    try {

      await logger.info(`Downloading File From S3 : ${key}`)
      const { Body } = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, Key: key }));
      const rows = [];
      const parser = Body.pipe(parse({
        columns: headers,
        from_line: offset + 2,
        to_line: offset + limit + 1
      }));
  
      for await (const record of parser) {
        await logger.info(__PREFIX, `Processing Row ${currentRow}`)
  
        SOME CODE PROCESSING CSV ROWS...
      }
  
      return {
        continueProcessing: processedRows === limit,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          ...body,
          offset: offset + processedRows,
          countTry: 0,
          headers,
        })
      };
    } catch (e) {
      await logger.error(__PREFIX, e, false)
      return {
        continueProcessing: countTry < maxTry,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          ...body,
          countTry: countTry + 1,
          headers,
        })
      };
    }
  })
};
```

Having the safeHandler being:

```
export async function safeHandler(prefix, fn) {
  try {
    // Trying to manually timeout before AWS cut the Lambda so we can have some better logging
    const timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Timeout')), (__TIMEOUT * 1000) - 2000)
      timeout.unref()
    })

    const res = await Promise.race([fn(), timeoutPromise])
    return res
  }
  catch (e) {
    await logger.error(prefix, e, false)
    await logger.error(prefix, e.message, !(DO_NOT_PUBLISH === 'true'))
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
    }
  }
}
```

And having those logs:

```
Mar 4, 2024, 22:01:00.539 (UTC+01:00)   START RequestId: 8a91277d-00cc-49cf-aadc-040dc057e1bb Version: $LATEST
Mar 4, 2024, 22:01:00.540 (UTC+01:00)   2024-03-04T21:01:00.540Z 8a91277d-00cc-49cf-aadc-040dc057e1bb INFO Connecting To Database...
Mar 4, 2024, 22:01:00.541 (UTC+01:00)   2024-03-04T21:01:00.541Z 8a91277d-00cc-49cf-aadc-040dc057e1bb INFO [TASK Lambda / Ingest Dataset] Downloading File From S3 : key.csv
Mar 4, 2024, 22:01:00.563 (UTC+01:00)   END RequestId: 8a91277d-00cc-49cf-aadc-040dc057e1bb
Mar 4, 2024, 22:01:00.563 (UTC+01:00)   REPORT RequestId: 8a91277d-00cc-49cf-aadc-040dc057e1bb Duration: 24.32 ms Billed Duration: 25 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 216 MB
```

So we can see that the function does not timeout.
I don't understand because there is no case where the return can be null.
I have tries/catches and when I restart the same step it works.

The bug seems to be "unstable". When the Payload is null I have no error log.

Comment: Yeah I think you are returning in some cases the results from the `timeoutPromise` and that is `null`. `Promise.race()` then resolves also to `null`. But I can't really understand in your code why this is happening